# Add input tag inside HTML via JS and increasing input id inside JS

Tags: javascript, html, input

I wanted to write a Website where you can write 3 E-Mails inside a Textinput. However I also added a Button which adds another Textinput for another E-Mail. My problem is, that I wanted to add the newly added Element a id with the following code: `email.setAttribute('id','increasing_number');`. However It doesn´t work how I want it to work. Full code and the Results:

```js
function test() {
    let ul =document.getElementById('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var y = 4;
    var email = document.createElement('input');
    email.setAttribute('id',y); //<--
    email.setAttribute('placeholder','E-Mail');
    email.setAttribute('type','email');
    email.setAttribute('name','email');
    email.setAttribute('required','');
    li.appendChild(email);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    y = y++;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>
        <input id="4" placeholder="E-Mail" type="email" name="email" required="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="4" placeholder="E-Mail" type="email" name="email" required="">
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can see that it should show for the 5th E-Mail `input id="5"` but it doesn´t. It shows the number 4. It doesn´t save the old value of y inside the JS file and doesn´t increase it properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: you need to declare y outside of the function. the way you have it, y gets reset to 4 every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your code initialize `y` as 4 everytime it runs. You can have a function parameter that holds the variable for id of an element and then you can call it in a for loop.

```
function test(id){
    let ul = document.getElementById('ul');
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let email = document.createElement('input');
    email.setAttribute('id', id);
    email.setAttribute('placeholder', 'E-mail');
    email.setAttribute('type', 'email');
    email.setAttribute('name', 'email');
    email.setAttribute('required','');
    li.appendChild(email);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

for(let i=1; i<=5; i++){
    test(i);
}
```